# best practise in allowing users to access specific features

Tags: php, security, authentication

My web app has different levels of users that have different access to the site. It important that users only be able to access their own level features, as for example the super users will have access to mass email, the ability to delete, access to more sensitive information user etc.

The main differences in access is via links in the menu area. Current it does this to decide upon access (using POST to send a userid which is stored in  session variable):

```
// and the userlevel (i.e. 50 for me, 10 for super user etc)
$query_ulevel = $database->prepare("SELECT ulevel FROM user_table WHERE id=?");
$query_ulevel->bind_param("i", $_POST['uid']);
$query_ulevel->execute();
$userlevel = $query_ulevel->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

To get the users level, and:

```
// super user options
if($userlevel['userlevel'] > 0) {
    ?><hr />

    <div onclick="user.liststatistics()" class="usermenu-line">
        Student Statistics
    </div>

    <?php 
}
```

to display it. With one glaring obvious problem of the fact that userids are auto increment and just numbers (as opposed to keys of length X which are randomly assigned when users sign up - a system I intend to convert to) is this the best way to go about it? Is there a way that users could circumvent this system? The fact that this is generated server side using PHP I think means its nice and safe, using POST and (eventual) random ID values means its difficult to force an ID into the file to output a result, and the main javascript file is obfuscated and minified meaning its less easy (but still probably easy if you know how) to read and find the name of the php file and location.

The question: Would this system be adequate to defend against fairly competent programmers from forcing their way into an admin account?

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: I'd be more inclined to retrieve the `ulevel` / roles / access control list for the user on authentication and store that in the session for later use. Relying on the client sending the correct user ID in a POST request is potentially dangerous